# Dynamic callback URL's for Instagram Auth

Tags: api, callback, oauth-2.0, instagram, instagram-api

I have different clients using my cloud app.

They all have different URL's to access the cloud application. They have the option to add Instagram as a social media channel and perform multiple tasks over it.

Now to perform any action over Instagram, they all need to authenticate themselves via myInstagram App. So I need to manually put a new callback URL every time a new client request for Instagram. Is there is any way to make Callback URL's dynamic on Instagram?